# How to perform a query over models with attributes stored in other models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class Constraint < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :constraint_category
end


class ConstraintCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :constraints
end
```

The models have these attributes (from db/schema.rb):

```
  create_table "constraint_categories", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "value"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.boolean  "active"
  end

  create_table "constraints", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "phrase"
    t.integer  "constraint_category_id", :limit => 255
    t.boolean  "active"
    t.datetime "created_at",                            :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                            :null => false
  end
```

I would like to create a query that finds all constraints where the "active" attribute is "true" and the "constraint_category.value" is "Noun".

Would love any advice on getting there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Constraint.joins(:constraint_category).where('constraints.active = ? and constraint_categories.value = ?', true, 'Noun')
```

See [conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions) and [joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) in the guide.

Comment: a little more cleaner Constraint.joins(:constraint_category).where(:active => true, :constraint_category => { :value => 'Noun'} )